# Import Gremlin Graphson into Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, gremlin

How can I import a Gremlin Graphson file into Neo4J with Cypher using one of Neo4J's provided default interfaces -- web interface or rest? I've dug through the documentation, but all I can find is direct CREATE statements or importing from CSV format.

Answer (score 2):

GraphSON is a TinkerPop format.  As of yet, I'm not sure that there are Neo4j native functions (via cypher or api) to import it.  In order to import it, you would have to open your graph with the TinkerPop's [Neo4jGraph](https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki/Neo4j-Implementation):

```
g = new Neo4jGraph("/tmp/mygraph")
```

and then import with the [GraphSONReader](https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki/GraphSON-Reader-and-Writer-Library) library:

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream("/tmp/my-graphson-file.json")
GraphSONReader.inputGraph(graph, in);
```